# Sencha Ext JS data not showing in grid

Tags: extjs

Hi im new to Sencha Extjs im trying to pull the data from the API that i created in asp.net.

in the developer tools i can get the data but it is not showing in the grid. Can anyone help?

here is the code that i did.

This is the Model

```
Ext.define('VidlyViews.model.Customers', {
extend: 'VidlyViews.model.Base',

fields: [
    'name', 'membershipType', 'isSubscribeToNewsLetter', 'birthDate'
]
```

});

This is the Store.

```
Ext.define('VidlyViews.store.Customers', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.customers',
model: 'VidlyViews.model.Customers',
autoLoad: true,

proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
    url: 'https://localhost:44300/api/customers',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'feed.entry'
    }
}
```

});

This is in the classic/src/view/main folder

```
Ext.define('VidlyViews.view.main.Customers', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
xtype: 'customerlist',

requires: [
    'VidlyViews.store.Customers'
],

title: 'Customers',

store: {
    type: 'customers'
},

columns: [
    { text: 'Customer Name',  dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1 },
    { text: 'Membership Type', dataIndex: 'membershipType', flex: 1 },
    { text: 'Newsletter', dataIndex: 'isSubscribeToNewsLetter', flex: 1 },
    { text: 'Birthdate', dataIndex: 'birthDate', flex: 1 }
],

listeners: {
    select: 'onItemSelected'
}
```

});

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed my problem and i hope it can help others in the future.

i changed my proxy to this:

```
proxy : {
    type : 'rest',
    actionMethods : {
       read : 'GET' 
    },
    url : 'https://localhost:44300/api/customers',
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    reader: {
       type : 'json',
       headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
       allDataOptions: {
            associated: true,
            persist: true
        },
       rootProperty : 'data'
    },
}
```

I used restto pull the data. and the rootPropery is the data.
In the API (ASP.NET) i modified the IhhtpActionResult to this

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCustomers(int start, int limit)
```

because in sencha you can get the start and limit of the pagination and use .Skip() and .Take() on the backend.

it looks like this:

```
var customerDtos = customersQuery
            .OrderBy(c => c.CustomerId)
            .Skip(start)
            .Take(limit)
            .ToList();
```

and the last step that i did is to return the data like this:

```
return Ok(new { total = customerDtos.Count(), data = customerDtos });
```

the data is recognized in the rootProperty as the collection of data and the total is the total count of the data that can be recognized in the API call.

I hope it helps. It took me a whole day to figure it out hahaha